# Validation in a webform

Tags: 8, webforms

I’m relatively new to webform and was able to create few with some basic functionalities.
Have a question, is it possible to implement this form (https://www.revenue.state.mn.us/local_gov/boa/Pages/AMA_Registration.aspx) in Drupal 8 webform module without custom code? What webform add-ons should be considered.
It seems like a set of 2 webforms where the fields in the second form are disabled and only enabled when the number in the first form is validated against a list of numbers.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I vote this question down because the link you shared is ends with aspx and it is advisable to share links to active sites here

Comment: .aspx is just a page extension for .Net. He's just demonstrating a form. Yes, Webform can build a form like that.

Comment: @IsmailCherri So is it advisable or not advisable, I'm confused! Also, did you even bother to read the question?!

Comment: Ok.. I removed the downvote

Comment: Yes you can do it with webform, and i think you will need [conditional fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) i notice that the other fields are disabled before licence validation.

Comment: @berramou Yes, that's true. However, the Webform module has its own conditions out of the box, so this shouldn't be an issue.